# Decrypting text file in openssl:-Error:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:

Tags: java, android, encryption, openssl

I'm writing a small application to learn more of encryption/decryption.
From my code I am generating AES key and then encrypting text file with AES key.After that I am encrypting AES key using RSA public key.

Below is the code snippet

```
SecretKey secretAesKey ;
KeyGenerator keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
keyGen.init(256);
secretAesKey = keyGen.generateKey();
if (secretAesKey != null) {
    Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretAesKey);
    long aesEncryptStartTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    CipherInputStream aesCis = new CipherInputStream(fis, aesCipher);
    int read;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    while ((read = aesCis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        aesFos.write(buffer, 0, read);
        aesFos.flush();
    }

    // Encrypt the generated key
    if (!encKeyFile.exists()) {
        encKeyFile.createNewFile();
    }

    try {
        byte[] encryptedAesKey = null;
        Cipher rsaCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
        rsaCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, readRsaPublicKeyFromResource(context));
        encryptedAesKey = rsaCipher.doFinal(secretAesKey.getEncoded());
        rsaFos.write(encryptedAesKey);
        rsaFos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "RSA encryption error", e);
    } finally {
        rsaFos.close();
    }
```

During decryption first decrypting AES key with RSA private key, from following code

```
FileInputStream keyFis = new FileInputStream(encKeyFile);
byte[] encKey = new byte[keyFis.available()];
keyFis.read(encKey);
keyFis.close();

SecretKey key = null;
PrivateKey privKey = readRsaPrivateKeyFromResource(context);
Cipher cipher = null;

try
{
    // initialize the cipher...
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
    // generate the aes key!
    key = new SecretKeySpec (cipher.doFinal(encKey), "AES" );
    String stringKey = Base64.encodeToString(key.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
    try {
        OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(context.openFileOutput("aesDecrypted.key", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
        outputStreamWriter.write(stringKey);
        outputStreamWriter.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("Exception", "File write failed: " + e.toString());
    }
```

I am getting decrypted AES key for example "ah3ZWMieji6KtSav6gaayTvsEID2vpp589wdChTLmZs="

After converting it into hex value it is as follows. "6A1DD958C89E8E2E8AB526AFEA069AC93BEC1080F6BE9A79F3DC1D0A14CB999B"

Trying to decrypt text file with generated hex key in terminal 
For e.g:

> openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -iv 0 -in encrypt.txt -out decrypt.txt -K
>   6A1DD958C89E8E2E8AB526AFEA069AC93BEC1080F6BE9A79F3DC1D0A14CB999B

I am getting following error

bad decrypt
7560:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:

Why would this be, and further, what am I doing incorrectly?

If anybody could help, I'd be very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have multiple problems with your code, here is a non-exhaustive list:

- Java automatically generates a random IV for you, but you forgot to save it for decryption (`cipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class));`). The IV is not secret. Usually, it is sent along with the ciphertext.
- Using `keyFis.available()` is a bad idea, because a stream doesn't tell you how big the underlying file is, but rather how many bytes are left in its internal buffer. Use a different technique to get the size of the file.
- You've tried to implement hybrid encryption. When decrypting you need to reverse the process: first use RSA to decrypt the AES key and then use AES to decrypt the actual data.

Comment: I have tried checking the generated key using following statement       String stringKey = Base64.encodeToString(secretAesKey.getEncoded(), Base64.DEFAULT);
It is same as that I am getting after decrypting AES key.  Can you elaborate about saving random IV keys .

Comment: I did: `aesCipher.getParameters().getParameterSpec(IvParameterSpec.class)).getIV();`

Comment: I tried adding IV keys in openssl command :-                                     
"openssl aes-256-cbc -d -a -iv 0037AC1DA2C0CE1C66AC3BF88D39ED92 -in encrypt.txt -out final.txt -K F6082422EC05FA3DC25E3FE6349401EFE6897581A99CF43A6486466B641D7C98"
bad decrypt
2780:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:518:

Still no luck.

Comment: @Pause option `-a` in openssl indicates the file is in base64 .. but your AES encrypted file is not in base64 ..